# Can't figure out javascript necessary to make Prev/Next buttons work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been reading a few articles on this site on how to do prev/next navigation, but I can't seem to find one that I can play nicely with the way I have my code set up. There's a lot to take in, if you'd like to see the live site for reference click [here](http://darrenbachan.com/#/s-trip).

**HTML**

```
<div id="arrow-nav" class="container-full clearfix">
   <div class="container">
      <a class="prev sm-title" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Previous Project<span>Project Title</span></a>
      <a class="next sm-title" href="#"><span>Project Title</span>Next Story <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
   </div>
</div><!--end arrow nav-->

<div id="portfolio">
   <div class="portfolio-container group">

   <div class="articles">
      <article class="mix web col-6" data-myorder="1">
         <div class="holder">
            <a href="" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-1" id="project_1"><span class="image_holder grow" style="background-image:url('images/file-thumb.jpg')"></span></a>
            <p class="description" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-1"><span>Project Name</span><br>Check out this project!</p>
         </div>
      </article>

      <article class="mix web col-6" data-myorder="2">
         <div class="holder">
            <a href="" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-2" id="project_2"><span class="image_holder grow" style="background-image:url('images/file-thumb.jpg')"></span></a>
            <p class="description" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-2"><span>Project Name</span><br>Check out this project!</p>
         </div>
      </article>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**
This is how I'm creating content for each project:

```
var projects = {
        'project-1' : {
            'title' : 'Project Name',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/path/file-1.jpg'
            ],
            'tags': [
                'Lorem Ipsum 1',
                'Lorem Ipsum 2'
            ]
        },
        'project-2' : {
            'title' : 'Project Name',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/path/file-1.jpg'
            ],
            'tags': [
                'Lorem Ipsum 1',
                'Lorem Ipsum 2'
            ]
        }
}
```

This is an example of how I'm pulling that data and spitting it out into a div:

```
$('#project-title').html(projectData.title);
$('#project-description').html(projectData.description);
```

This is how I get the `#arrow-nav` to appear:

```
$('[data-type="projectLoader"]').click(function() {
        var proj = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-project');
        $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');

        updateHash(proj);
        return false;
});

$('[data-type="projectDie"]').click(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');
        $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
        return false;
});

$( 'document' ).ready(function() {
        if ($('body').hasClass('projectLoaded')) {
            $('#arrow-nav').addClass('slideIn');
        } else {
            $('#arrow-nav').removeClass('slideIn');
        }
});
```

It's a lot of code to take in. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is, when I hover over Previous or Next I have a `<span>` that I'd like to hold the previous or next project name in. Prev/Next would either take the `data-myorder="x";` or grab the prev/next project from `var projects`.

The interaction when clicking on a project, this is the css that makes it slide up:

```
#project {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    opacity:0;
    top:100%;
    background: #efefed;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;

    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
body.projectLoaded {
    overflow: hidden;
}
body.projectLoaded #project {
    opacity:1;
    top:0;
}
```

It would be neat if when I click on the Previous button it goes from left:100%; to left:0 and vice versa, but if it had to remain the same I can live with that. I tried looking at some examples to see if it were simple enough to swap things around, I've tried a few code samples but I didn't know what I was doing so I didn't bother to post any of that code here, there's already a lot. For a visual idea of what I'm trying to achieve click [here](http://darrenbachan.com/) and click on a project.

Comment: How are you determining what projects navigate to where?

Comment: @AdamCarr  It needs to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want things sliding from left to right, depending on the direction you're going, you need three separate states: left/right/active

You can create a div to hold your next/prev states so that you can slide them in while the active one slides away.

Before anything slides, you update the information from the slide coming in.

You know which project is active, so you know where to go from there.

I would change your JS object to:

```
var projects = [
    {
            'id': 1,
        'title' : 'Project Name',
        'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
        'images': [
            '/images/path/file-1.jpg'
        ],
        'tags': [
            'Lorem Ipsum 1',
            'Lorem Ipsum 2'
        ]
    },
    {
            'id': 2,
        'title' : 'Project Name',
        'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
        'images': [
            '/images/path/file-1.jpg'
        ],
        'tags': [
            'Lorem Ipsum 1',
            'Lorem Ipsum 2'
        ]
    }
 ];

 console.log(projects[0].tags); // ["Lorem Ipsum 1", "Lorem Ipsum 2"]
```

Now you can work with the index of the array, or the ID.

For the animation here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsonalberto/n2seshef/)

**EDIT:** [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsonalberto/zx5fjd99/) illustrates my point better

Comment: this is an example on how to target "tags" so I can target "title" if I wanted to, but how do I pull the prev and next project? Like the entire "projects" of it?

Comment: @DarrenBachan I've updated my answer with the behavior I think you require.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the visible article just by a little jquery code without changing your other functions.

this example can help you.

I did not change your html ids, so you can just copy the jquery code and enjoy it ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.articles').children().not(':first').hide();
  $('.prev').hide();
  
  $('.articles').on('next', function(){
   var current = $('.articles article:visible'),
   current_index = current.data('myorder'),
    count = $('.articles article').length;
    if (current_index < count)
    {
     if(current_index == 1)
       $('.prev').show();
     if(current_index == count - 1)
       $('.next').hide();
     current.hide();
      current.next().show();
    }
  });
  
  $('.articles').on('prev', function(){
   var current = $('.articles article:visible'),
   current_index = current.data('myorder'),
    count = $('.articles article').length;
    if (current_index > 1)
    {
     if(current_index == count)
       $('.next').show();
     if(current_index == 2)
       $('.prev').hide();
     current.hide();
      current.prev().show();
    }
  });
  
  $('.next').on('click', function(){
   $('.articles').trigger('next');
    return false;
  });
  $('.prev').on('click', function(){
   $('.articles').trigger('prev');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="arrow-nav" class="container-full clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="prev sm-title" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i> Previous Project<span>Project Title</span></a>
    <a class="next sm-title" href="#"><span>Project Title</span>Next Story <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end arrow nav-->

<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio-container group">

    <div class="articles">
      <article class="mix web col-6" data-myorder="1">
         <div class="holder">
            <a href="" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-1" id="project_1"><span class="image_holder grow" style="background-image:url('images/file-thumb.jpg')"></span></a>
            <p class="description" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-1"><span>Project Name</span><br>Check out this project!</p>
         </div>
      </article>

      <article class="mix web col-6" data-myorder="2">
         <div class="holder">
            <a href="" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-2" id="project_2"><span class="image_holder grow" style="background-image:url('images/file-thumb.jpg')"></span></a>
            <p class="description" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-2"><span>Project Name</span><br>Check out this project!</p>
         </div>
      </article>
      
      <article class="mix web col-6" data-myorder="3">
        <div class="holder">
            <a href="" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-3" id="project_3"><span class="image_holder grow" style="background-image:url('images/file-thumb.jpg')"></span></a>
            <p class="description" data-type="projectLoader" data-project="project-2"><span>Project Name</span><br>Check out this project!</p>
         </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**get current article from the var**

when you get your projectData from the projects var, you should get the index of the project and save it in the #project-container html data by this code when you drawing your project:

```
$('#project-container').data('index', n);
```

then you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
  $('.articles').on('next', function(){
    var current_index = $('#project-container').data('index'),
    count = projects.length;
    if (current_index < count)
    {
      projectData = projects[current_index+1];

      /* now update #project-container with your functions */
    }
  });

  $('.articles').on('prev', function(){
    var current_index = $('#project-container').data('index'),
    count = projects.length;
    if (current_index > 1)
    {  
      projectData = projects[current_index-1];

      /* now update #project-container with your functions */
    }
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function(){
    $('.articles').trigger('next');
    return false;
  });
  $('.prev').on('click', function(){
    $('.articles').trigger('prev');
    return false;
  });
});
```

note 1: start indexes from 1.

note 2: use your project container drawer function to update #project-container in below code.

Comment: This is close, this is pulling the content from the article, the content comes from the strings inside var projects.

Comment: you can use your previous functions to get articles from the var project, and then add this code for paging articles.
is your problem to fetch articles from the var project ???

Comment: I dont need anything from the articles, I need what's in the strings and substrings. It spits it out into #project-container.

Comment: see the end of my answer. there is a new solution.